# angular send OPTION request instead of POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two web server, both are run in localhost but port no is different

1. http://localhost:8080
2. http://localhost:8000

my 2nd server for api and 1st one for frontend
1st server serve angular script and when angular send a post request to 2nd server then post are changed to option, I don’t know what happened also I have search lots but does not got any solve.

also i have change my api server response header to

```
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'
response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE'
```

i know this problem occur for cross domain problem please help me.

AngularJS v1.4.7

angular code is bellow

```
return $http.post(apiConfig.server + 'login/',$.param({
  'email': email,
  'password': password
}))
.success(function(data){
  AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
  return data;
})
.error(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Having a different port *is* a cross domain request. So you need to do what you do for a CORS, which I assume you can find online.

Comment: yes i have do all in server side for api but does not work

Comment: You'll need to update your question with what you have done, and what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: does not work means $http.post send option request not post request

Comment: Browser sends OPTIONS request...not `$http`. Problem  means you haven't implemented CORS properly. Post sample of response headers returned in OPTIONS request

Comment: when i have tested api from postman then it work but from angular it not work

Comment: Missing method for `"OPTIONS"`. Postman is not subject to CORS restrictions...browsers are

Comment: Also might need to allow credentials with header and set `withCredentials` header in request. See `$http` docs

Comment: thank you @charli but not work i have add this method

Comment: I don't think you can use `*` for the CORS origins if you're using auth.  I could be mistaken though.